# converting rows to columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data set like this

```
movieID    title   year   country    genre  directorName    Rating     actorName1     actorName.2
1          hello    1995    USA      action    john smith       6        tom hanks      charlie sheen
2          MI2      1997    USA      action    mad max          8        tom cruize     some_body
3          MI2      1997    USA      thriller  mad max          8        tom cruize     some_body
```

basically there are numerous rows that just have a different user given genre that I would like to columns having genre1, genre2, ...

I tried reshape() but it would only convert based on some ID variable. If anyone has any ideas let me know

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reshape()` to do this, if you understand the lens through which `reshape()` views data.

---

## Background

First, consider the concept of a **record** in the context of the [relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) of data management. Generally, in a table of data, each record should correspond to a well-defined *unit of data*, concisely termed the **record unit**, with one or more columns acting as *identification* or *key* variables that serve to differentiate between unique instances of the record unit.

Usually, units are described by a set of scalar variables. In other words, each record has associated with it one or more scalar values, each of which provides a single piece of information about the unit. In a nice simple world, *all* properties of units would be scalar, and thus you could represent each variable as a single column vector, with each element/cell corresponding to one record unit, and thereby providing the value of that particular property for that particular unit.

---

Further to the concept of properties, it is possible and very common to identify *typing* or *grouping* classifications of units. These are often represented as additional scalar properties of units.

When people talk about the *long format* vs. the *wide format* of tabular data, they are generally referring to how these kinds of type classifications are laid out in a table. This choice of data layout is directly related to the choice of unit that is represented by a single record in the table. These are actually one and the same choice.

For example, in an experiment with multiple measurements per individual, it would be possible to store one measurement per record, with individuals represented over multiple records, and a type column to distinguish between measurement type. Alternatively, it would be possible to store one individual per record, with each measurement represented by a single column. With respect to each other, the former format is long, and the latter format is wide. But now consider that, if each individual belonged to a single experimental group within the experiment, it would be possible to store one group per record, with each individual represented by a set of columns, and each measurement represented by one column within the set. This is yet a "wider" format, if you will. It's all relative.

---

Unfortunately, unit characteristics are sometimes more complex than simple scalar values. The most common case of this is a multivalue property, sometimes described as a many-to-one relationship (especially in the context of DBMSs). In other words, multiple values for the property can be associated with a single record unit. In cases like this, it is not possible to represent the multivalue property as a simple column vector within the data set. There are hacks that programmers often settle into when trying to deal with this complexity, such as:

- Concatenating the multiple values into a single scalar value (such as a single comma-separated string, or a bit vector). Let's call this the "concatenation hack".
- Duplicating the unit record for each value of the property. (This generally can only be plausible if only one of the properties in the data set is multivalue.) Let's call this the "duplication hack".
- Separating the property into multiple "instances" of itself, each stored in its own column. Let's call this the "separation hack".
- Simply trying to ignore all but one of the multiple values. Let's call this the "ignorance hack".

In some contexts, special data types can be used to more appropriately represent the data as a pseudo-column-vector. PostgreSQL, for example, provides an [array column type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html), and even R data.frames can have list columns whose individual elements can hold any data type supported by R, including multielement vectors. These representations are usually preferable to the aforementioned hacks.

Probably the most widely used solution that I wouldn't qualify as a hack is to completely separate the multivalue property from the primary table of data, and instead store it as a separate table which is linked to the primary table on a key. Each record in the secondary table has a key to a record in the primary table, and stores alongside the key a single value of the multivalue property. This is the design advocated by the relational model.

These approaches all have their own tradeoffs, of course, and the analysis of which is optimal for a given situation can be very complex, nebulous, and even somewhat subjective. I won't go into more detail on this here.

---

Before I begin to talk about `reshape()`, it is important to emphasize that unit typing is a very different thing from multivalue properties. Reshaping data is generally supposed to be about managing typing and record unit selection. It is not supposed to be about managing multivalue property layout, but it can be used in this way, as we will see.

---

## [`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reshape.html)

At its most abstract, `reshape()` can be used to transform a set of typed scalar **data columns** from one *row* per type with a **discriminator column** to one *column* per type with a **discriminator suffix** in the column name, for every unique (possibly multicolumn) **key**, and vice-versa.

The key will generally correspond with a single record unit, to use the terminology introduced earlier. Each key uniquely identifies one record unit.

The data columns are the actual variables/properties which describe the record units, with the discriminator acting to distinguish between the different types of the data variables.

In the terminology of the `reshape()` documentation and interface, the key columns are "id" columns, the discriminator is the "time" column, and the data columns are "varying" columns.

It is important to understand that the key you specify as the `idvar` argument is always the unique key of the *wide* format, whether you are transforming *to* wide from long, or to long *from* wide. In the long format, the unique key is the `idvar` columns *plus* the discriminator column (`timevar`).

Here's a simple demo:

```
## define example long table
long <- data.frame(id1=rep(letters[1:2],each=4L),id2=rep(1:2,each=2L),type=1:2,x=1:8,y=9:16);
long;
##   id1 id2 type x  y
## 1   a   1    1 1  9
## 2   a   1    2 2 10
## 3   a   2    1 3 11
## 4   a   2    2 4 12
## 5   b   1    1 5 13
## 6   b   1    2 6 14
## 7   b   2    1 7 15
## 8   b   2    2 8 16

## convert to wide
idvar <- c('id1','id2');
timevar <- 'type';
wide <- reshape(long,dir='w',idvar=idvar,timevar=timevar);
attr(wide,'reshapeWide') <- NULL; ## remove "helper" attribute, which cannot always be relied upon
wide;
##   id1 id2 x.1 y.1 x.2 y.2
## 1   a   1   1   9   2  10
## 3   a   2   3  11   4  12
## 5   b   1   5  13   6  14
## 7   b   2   7  15   8  16

## convert back to long
long2 <- reshape(wide,dir='l',idvar=idvar,timevar=timevar,varying=names(wide)[!names(wide)%in%c(idvar,timevar)]);
attr(long2,'reshapeLong') <- NULL; ## remove "helper" attribute, which cannot always be relied upon
long2 <- long2[do.call(order,long2[c(idvar,timevar)]),]; ## better order, corresponding with original long
rownames(long2) <- NULL; ## remove useless row names
long2$type <- as.integer(long2$type); ## annoyingly, longifying interprets discriminator suffixes as doubles
identical(long,long2);
## [1] TRUE
```

The above code also demonstrates some of the quirks committed by `reshape()`, such as attribute assignments (that I've never seen anyone rely upon), unexpected row order, undesirable row names, and non-ideal vector type derivation. All of these quirks can be papered over with simple modifications, as I show above.

Also notice that the `varying` argument can be omitted when transforming from long to wide, in which case it is derived by `reshape()` by the process of elimination, but it cannot be omitted when transforming from wide to long.

---

## Input

The situation you've gotten yourself into appears to be that you have a data.frame that is *supposed* to contain one row per movie, but each movie record has been duplicated for each genre that is associated with the movie. In other words, the *movie* is the record unit, and the *genre* is a multivalue property associated with the movie, which is currently being represented by the duplication hack.

Your objective seems to be to transform the data from the duplication hack into the separation hack.

I don't mean to sound too critical here; these hacks are widely used and are, in many cases, fairly effective at handling this kind of complexity in a relatively simple way. It's very likely this is a good solution for your application. But I'm going to call a spade a spade; these are hacks, and are far from the most appropriate or robust solutions for data processing. And I agree that the separation hack is better than the duplication hack.

---

Another confusing detail is that there is a `movieID` column which appears to be unique per row, and *not* unique per movie. IDs 2 and 3 both seem to be associated with movie MI2.

My interpretation is that, in the input, because the duplication hack has been used to deal with multiple genres, each row can be thought of as being unique per *genre instance*. In other words, each row represents a single instance of a genre as used in a single movie. Hence the `movieID` column is better thought of as a *genre instance identifier*, and has just been misnamed. (An alternative interpretation is that it was generated incorrectly, and should be unique per movie, in which case it should be fixed and treated identically to the key columns described later.)

---

## Solution

We can solve this problem by calling `reshape()` to transform from long format to wide format.

Recall that reshaping is supposed to be used for type layout, for navigating between record unit representations. Here we're instead going to use it for transforming how the multivalue property currently stored in the `genre` column is laid out.

Now, the most important question is, which columns are keys (`idvar`), which is the discriminator (`timevar`), and which are data (`varying`)?

The easiest one is the `genre` column. It's a data column. It's not part of the key that will help uniquely identify each movie record in the wide format, and it's certainly not a discriminator of other data columns, so it must be a data column itself. We can also arrive at this answer by considering what must happen to it during the transformation; for each unique key, the genre values must be separated from one row per value to one column per value, which is what happens to all data columns when transforming from long to wide.

Now it's useful to consider the discriminator column. Which one is it? In actuality, it doesn't exist in the input. There's no column that says "this is genre type X, this is genre type Y". So what do we do? According to your required output, you want to associate with each genre a sequential index number, presumably in row order. This means we need to synthesize a new column with such a sequence when passing the data.frame to `reshape()`. However, we must be careful to ensure that the sequence starts anew for each movie, otherwise every record in the input table would see its genre occupy its own column in the output, due to its unique discriminator suffix. We can do this with [`ave()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ave.html) (grouping by the key columns) and [`transform()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/transform.html). We'll name the synthesized column `time`, which is the default assumption by `reshape()` if you don't specify the `timevar` argument. This will allow us to omit specification of that argument. (Note: I've always wished that `reshape()` would default to such a row-order sequence instead of looking for an input column named `time`, but it doesn't do that. Oh well.)

Now let's deal with the `movieID` column. Being a unique identifier in the input table, the only way to include it in the output table would be to also treat it as a data column, so that it would be split by the discriminator into separate columns. I decided to make the assumption that you don't want to do this, so I just removed it from the input table before reshaping, by exploiting the same `transform()` call. If you want, you can excise the removal piece to see the effect of including `movieID` across the transformation.

That leaves the remaining columns of `title`, `year`, `country`, `directorName`, `Rating`, `actorName1`, and `actorName.2`. How should we treat these?

Technically speaking, conceptually, most of them should be data columns. They can't be discriminators (we already covered that), and there's no way most of them (`Rating`, for example) could be considered key columns. Again, conceptually.

But it would be incorrect to specify any of them as data columns. The reason is that we're not using `reshape()` in the normal way. We know the movie records have been duplicated for the `genre` duplication hack used by the input data.frame, and so all the columns I just listed are actually just duplicates within the movie record group. We need these columns to effectively collapse to a single record in the output, and that's exactly what happens with key columns that pass through a `reshape()` call. Hence, we must identify them all as key columns by passing them to the `idvar` argument.

Another way of thinking about this is that the key columns are left untouched by `reshape()`, other than deduplication (if going from long to wide) or duplication (if going from wide to long). It is only the discriminator column that is transferred from column to suffix (if going from long to wide) or vice-versa (if going from wide to long), and data columns that are transferred from single column to multiple columns (if going from long to wide) or vice-versa (if going from wide to long). We need these columns to remain untouched, other than deduplication. Hence we require *all* columns, other than the target multivalue property column `genre` and the synthesized `time` column (and, in this case, the extraneous `movieID` column) to be specified as key columns.

Note that this is true even if one or more of the key columns could serve as a true key for the movie records. For example, if `title` was known to be unique within the table by movie, it would still be incorrect to just specify `title` as the key, and all the other column names I listed as data columns, because they would then be widened in the output according to the synthesized discriminator, even though we know all values within each movie record group are identical.

So, here's the end result:

```
df <- data.frame(movieID=c(1L,2L,3L),title=c('hello','MI2','MI2'),year=c(1995L,1997L,1997L),country=c('USA','USA','USA'),genre=c('action','action','thriller'),directorName=c('john smith','mad max','mad max'),Rating=c(6L,8L,8L),actorName1=c('tom hanks','tom cruize','tom cruize'),actorName.2=c('charlie sheen','some_body','some_body'),stringsAsFactors=F);
idcns <- names(df)[!names(df)%in%c('movieID','genre')];
reshape(transform(df,movieID=NULL,time=ave(df$movieID,df[idcns],FUN=seq_along)),dir='w',idvar=idcns,sep='');
##   title year country directorName Rating actorName1   actorName.2 genre1   genre2
## 1 hello 1995     USA   john smith      6  tom hanks charlie sheen action     <NA>
## 2   MI2 1997     USA      mad max      8 tom cruize     some_body action thriller
```

Note that it is irrelevant exactly which vector is passed as the first argument to `ave()`, since `seq_along()` ignores its argument, except for its length. But we do require an integer vector, since `ave()` tries to coerce its result to the same type as the argument. It is acceptable to use `df$movieID` because it is an integer vector; alternatively we could use `df$year`, `df$Rating`, or synthesize an integer vector with `seq_len(nrow(df))` or `integer(nrow(df))`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with dplyr and tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(yesno=1) %>% spread(genre, yesno, fill=0)
```

This creates a column yesno that just gives a value to fill in for each genre.  We can then use spread from tidyr.  fill=0 means to fill in those not in the genre with 0 instead of NA.

Before:

```
     genre         title yesno
1   action lethal weapon     1
2 thriller       shining     1
3   action         taken     1
4    scifi         alien     1
```

After:

```
          title action scifi thriller
1         alien      0     1        0
2 lethal weapon      1     0        0
3       shining      0     0        1
4         taken      1     0        0
```

Comment: can I have this as different columns like genre1, genre2, genre3. I would not mind having the last few columns like genre5 to be NA

Comment: Have what as different columns?  each genre is a different column.

Comment: that would increase my number of columns as there are 23 unique genres. any workaround that?

Comment: I thought that is what you wanted.  What are you doing with these columns?  What would genre1 represent if it wasn't a particular genre?