# Converting rows into columns does not work with a big data frame

Tags: r

How do I efficiently convert rows into columns? This question has been asked before  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371162/converting-rows-to-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-r/37375812) but it does not work when you have a larger data frame. I attempted to make example data of a larger scale but its not quite the same as what I have. In reality, my data does not repeat over and over again. My real data is 6 columns by 4,000 rows. The solution described below works on the mock example but not my real data.

What does repeat is the condition described below where you have multiple rows that only differ in one column, in the case below the "description_9 column". Instead of having multiple rows where only one column is the difference I would like to compress the data so that the column is split into multiple columns. It can be a 5 columns for all I know.

Any help would be appreciated! Even help with making a more realistic example would be great!

## My data looks like this

```
      #fake data 
    condition_group <- c("nevous system", "nevous system",


"nevous system","circulatory system problems", 
 "circulatory system problems")
        sub_category    <- c("disease A", "disease A",  
    "disease A","disease B", "disease C")
        code_red        <- c(1,1,1,2,3)
        code_orange     <- c("x24", "x24","x24", "j897", "23a")
        description_9    <- c("mucous / mucous", "non maternal fetus", "third", "hello", "NA")
        description_10    <- c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "blue")

        df <- cbind.data.frame(condition_group, sub_category,
     code_red, code_orange, description_9, description_10 )


print(df2)
```

## This solution only works on small data

```
#reshape data 
     df$fake_id       <- c(seq(1, nrow(df)))
     idcns            <- names(df)[!names(df)%in%c('fake_id','description_9')];
     reformatted_data <- reshape(transform(df,fake_id=NULL,time=ave(df$fake_id,df[idcns],FUN=seq_along)),dir='w',idvar=idcns,sep='');
    #change na to blanks
    df2 <- reformatted_data 
    df2 <- sapply(df2, as.character) # since your values are `factor`
    df2[is.na(df2)] <- ""
    print(df2)
```

## Attempt at example of what happens with large data

```
# # this doesnt work with lots of data 
    larger_data <- rbind(df, df, df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df)

    larger_data <-rbind(larger_data, larger_data, larger_data, larger_data,
larger_data, larger_data, larger_data, larger_data, larger_data, larger_data, larger_data, larger_data,larger_data, larger_data, larger_data, larger_data,larger_data, larger_data, larger_data, larger_data)

df_larger <- rbind(larger_data, larger_data, larger_data, larger_data,larger_data, larger_data, larger_data, larger_data, larger_data)
#reshape data 
df_larger$fake_id       <- c(seq(1, nrow(df_larger)))
idcns            <- names(df_larger)[!names(df_larger)%in%c('fake_id','description_9')];
reformatted_data <- reshape(transform(df_larger,fake_id=NULL,time=ave(df_larger$fake_id,df_larger[idcns],FUN=seq_along)),dir='w',idvar=idcns,sep='');
```

Comment: There are `lareger_data` and `larger_data` in your code. You may want to make sure if those are typos.

Comment: After I changed some `lareger_data` to `larger_data`, your code works. `df_lareger` has 720 rows. Is that large enough?

Comment: Those are typos. I'll fix them. Yes, the code does work but on real data it does not. I let it run for over 15 minutes with the real example and it didn't finish. This sample large data is a bad example.

Comment: It could be helpful to know how large (like how many rows and columns) your real world dataset is.

Comment: How did the dplyr/tidyr solution provided in the linked question do, in terms of performance?

Comment: The dplyr/tyidyr solution returns a binary data frame. The real data is 6 by 4,000.